# Navigation bar - show, hide home and recents buttons

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to hide only home and recents button on system navigation bar ? I see that there is only possibility to show/hide whole system navigation bar, but I would like to stay with only back button visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

no you can't.
You can only hide it. See [android developers guide](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/).

Answer (score 0):

it's a hack but might fulfil your need:

Step1)Hide the  navigation bar or going with full screen (with UI flags).

Step2)Then implement an custom view (navigation bar) and add only back button(triangle) and override it's action to the onBackPressed method of the Activity class.